# JList alphabetical ordering

Tags: java, swing

I have the following demo app which displays a list of values, but i need to be able
to control the ordering of the elements in the list. Whats the easiest way to add this?

```
package demo;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListModel;

public class JListOrder {

    public JListOrder()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JListOrder");

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("z");
        model.addElement("Z");
        model.addElement("a");
        model.addElement("A");
        model.addElement("C");
        model.addElement("c");
        model.addElement("b");
        model.addElement("B");

        JList list = new JList(model);
        frame.add(list);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JListOrder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use SwingX which supports sorting/filtering of JXList the same way as core table sorting/filtering:

```
JXList list = new JXList(model);
list.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
list.toggleSortOrder();
```

Comment: No need to use a separate library. Just extend AbstractListModel and use a SortedSet like TreeSet to hold the elements. Here's an implementation: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SortedListModelsortableJList.htm ([archive](https://archive.today/EoFvn)). Or use this quick fork I made to add generics: https://gist.github.com/theAprel/bc661668d7120756b4a8

Comment: if you don't care about selection state ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean, you need to control the ordering of its elements during runtime, while its items are changing, then you probably need to implement your own SortedListModel for your JList. A nice article from oracle can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/sorted_jlist/).

Comment: might be considered a nice article - but it's not working reliable: as always with such decorator approaches (and the JList unaware of the fact) it's hard to get the notifications correct. Particularly tricky when doing anything on selection changes: the index conversion might be invalid while the sorted model processes a data event.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the hassle of sorting the objects before you add them to the JList, you can write/use a ListModel implementation that keeps them sorted for you already.  See e.g. [this implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SortedListModelsortableJList.htm).

As I say in almost every question related to JLists/JTables, please check out [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/).  It does just about everything you could imagine with respect to sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultListModel` displays elements in the order they're added.  You can just add the elements in order and that's how they'll be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sorted Combo Box Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/sorted-combo-box-model/). I know is says "combo box", but it also implements the List interface.

Comment: strictly speaking, that's violating MutableComboBoxModel contract on ~insertElementAt(value, index)~ - which I interpret as ~assertEquals(value, model.getElementAt(index))~ (hmm .. any way to format code snippets in a comment? Help seems to say tag in ~ code ~)